# How to see which application is intercepting certain key combinations?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

Yesterday, I noticed that "Alt+R" wasn't working. Anywhere. Other key combinations with Alt were working normally.

So I fired up Eclipse, went to keyboard shortcut settings and saw that I can't map "Alt+R" to anything. From these findings it was obvious that something, somewhere has globally registered this key combo.

After some trial and error, I found a non obvious thing: when Chrome is launched, the combo doesn't work. When it's closed, it works. It turned out a certain Chrome Extension was trapping this very combo. After disabling it, everything was back to normal.

Now, I'm wondering, is there a tool or utility that could help me pinpoint problems like this in the future? Something that says "this key combo is being intercepted by application or process XYZ"?

Answer (score 3):

There is small, freeware application called [ActiveHotkeys](http://ethervane.com/new-products/activehotkeys/download-activehotkeys), but it just shows active key combinations.

From ActiveHotkeys webpage:

> *Windows does not provide information about what program registered a particular global hotkey. Therefore this information is not available through ActiveHotkeys either.*